# Service running on another Service throw AggregateException in staging server (not in production)

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

We have a service

RENEWAL (service run in cl-app1) using a service "UQPDF" (using https://abc/Html2Pdf.svc in server cl-web1)

when I try to publish RENEWAL  with same content but a staging version of
it in cl-app2 using a staging service "UQPDF" (using https://abc-staging/Html2Pdf.svc in server cl-web2)

there is no error for production which is the one in cl-app1 and call cl-web1 pdf service,
and no problem running locally for staging RENEWAL.
the only problem is when I publish it in app2 using https://abc-staging/Html2Pdf.svc.

it throws the following exception

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'EmailToPdf_Staging.IHtml2PdfService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

AppConfig of Renewal

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IHtml2PdfService" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" allowCookies="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
            maxArrayLength="200000000" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
              establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://abc/Html2Pdf.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHtml2PdfService"
        contract="EmailToPdf.IHtml2PdfService" name="WSHttpBinding_IHtml2PdfService" />
      <endpoint address="https://abc-staging/Html2Pdf.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHtml2PdfService"
        contract="EmailToPdf_Staging.IHtml2PdfService" name="WSHttpBinding_IHtml2PdfService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

UQPDF Webconfig

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IHtml2PdfService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
                         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536000" maxArrayLength="65536000" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                                  maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="None"
                                negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                                establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="Ubiquity.uSuite3.PdfServices.Html2PdfService" behaviorConfiguration="uqpdf.ServiceBehavior">
                <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHtml2PdfService"
                          contract="Ubiquity.uSuite3.PdfServices.IHtml2PdfService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="uqpdf.ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your client did not find your contract through your configuration file.You can refer to my configuration.

Here is my demo:

```
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8012/ServiceModelSamples/service"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="Client4.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Client4" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8012/ServiceModelSamples/service"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="Client2.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Client2" />
        </client>
```

This is the configuration file of the endpoint,I suggest you do not set their names to the same.

```
            ChannelFactory<Client4.IService1> Client4 = new ChannelFactory<Client4.IService1>("BasicHttpBinding_Client4");
            Client4.IService1 chanel4 = Client4.CreateChannel();


            ChannelFactory<Client2.IService1> Client2 = new ChannelFactory<Client2.IService1>("BasicHttpBinding_Client2");
            Client2.IService1 chanel2 = Client2.CreateChannel();
```

We create different channels according to different endpoints to call services.